# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [3] vs. [8]?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp

I use `BERT` to do binary classifier，the batch size is 8, but when I calculate the loss value, always get the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1356, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1341, in _run_fn
>       options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>       run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>   Incompatible shapes: [3] vs. [8]   [[{{node
>   gradients/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:/project_chris/aad_bert_version/run.py", line 81, in 
>       input_y: y_train})   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 950, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1173, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1350, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1370, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>   Incompatible shapes: [3] vs. [8]   [[node
>   gradients/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at
>   E:/project_chris/aad_bert_version/run.py:57) ]]
>
> Original stack trace for 'gradients/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs':
>   File "E:/project_chris/aad_bert_version/run.py", line 57, in 
>       train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py",
>   line 403, in minimize
>       grad_loss=grad_loss)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py",
>   line 512, in compute_gradients
>       colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py",
>   line 158, in gradients
>       unconnected_gradients)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_util.py",
>   line 731, in _GradientsHelper
>       lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_util.py",
>   line 403, in _MaybeCompile
>       return grad_fn()  # Exit early   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_util.py",
>   line 731, in 
>       lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_grad.py",
>   line 1027, in _SubGrad
>       rx, ry = gen_array_ops.broadcast_gradient_args(sx, sy)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 1004, in broadcast_gradient_args
>       "BroadcastGradientArgs", s0=s0, s1=s1, name=name)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 788, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py",
>   line 507, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 3616, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2005, in **init**
>       self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
>
> ...which was originally created as op 'sub', defined at:   File
>   "E:/project_chris/aad_bert_version/run.py", line 56, in 
>       loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.reshape(pred, [-1]) - tf.reshape(input_y, [-1])))   File
>   "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
>   line 884, in binary_op_wrapper
>       return func(x, y, name=name)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
>   line 11574, in sub
>       "Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 788, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py",
>   line 507, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 3616, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Meiwei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2005, in **init**
>       self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

```
lr = 0.0006  # 学习率
# 配置文件
data_root = './bert_model_chinese'
bert_config_file = os.path.join(data_root, 'bert_config.json')
bert_config = modeling.BertConfig.from_json_file(bert_config_file)
init_checkpoint = os.path.join(data_root, 'bert_model.ckpt')
bert_vocab_file = os.path.join(data_root, 'vocab.txt')
token = tokenization.CharTokenizer(vocab_file=bert_vocab_file)

input_ids = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, None], name='input_ids')
input_mask = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, None], name='input_masks')
segment_ids = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, None], name='segment_ids')
input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name="input_y")
weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([768, 1]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1, ]))
}

model = modeling.BertModel(
    config=bert_config,
    is_training=False,
    input_ids=input_ids,
    input_mask=input_mask,
    token_type_ids=segment_ids,
    use_one_hot_embeddings=False)

tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
(assignment, initialized_variable_names) = modeling.get_assignment_map_from_checkpoint(tvars, init_checkpoint)
tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(init_checkpoint, assignment)
output_layer_pooled = model.get_pooled_output()  # 这个获取句子的output
output_layer_pooled = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer_pooled, keep_prob=0.9)

w_out = weights['out']
b_out = biases['out']
pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(output_layer_pooled, w_out), b_out, name="pre1")
pred = tf.reshape(pred, shape=[-1, 1], name="pre")

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.reshape(pred, [-1]) - tf.reshape(input_y, [-1])))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)



EPOCHS = 5
max_sentence_length = 512
batch_size = 8
data_path = './data'
train_input,predict_input =fffffuck(data_path,bert_vocab_file,True,True,
                                               './temp',max_sentence_length,batch_size,batch_size,batch_size)
data_loader = TextLoader(train_input,batch_size)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(EPOCHS):
        data_loader.shuff()
        for j in range(data_loader.num_batches):
            x_train, y_train = data_loader.next_batch(j)
            print(y_train)
            print(y_train.shape)
            x_input_ids = x_train[0]
            x_input_mask = x_train[1]
            x_segment_ids = x_train[2]
            loss_, _ = sess.run([loss, train_op],
                                feed_dict={input_ids: x_input_ids, input_mask: x_input_mask, segment_ids: x_segment_ids,
                                           input_y: y_train})
            print('loss:', loss_)


class TextLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, dataSet,batch_size):
        self.data = dataSet
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuff()

    def shuff(self):
        self.num_batches = int(len(self.data) // self.batch_size)
        if self.num_batches == 0:
            assert False, 'Not enough data, make batch_size small.'
        np.random.shuffle(self.data)

    def next_batch(self,k):
        x = []
        y = []
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            tmp = list(self.data)[k*self.batch_size + i][:3]
            x.append(tmp)
            y_ = list(self.data)[k*self.batch_size + i][3]
            y.append(y_)
        x = np.array(x)
        return x,np.array(y).reshape([self.batch_size,1])
```

Comment: Try changing `tmp = list(self.data)[k*self.batch_size + i][:3]` to `tmp = list(self.data)[k*self.batch_size + i][:self.batchsize]`

Comment: also, the same with `_ = list(self.data)[k*self.batch_size + i][3]` to `_ = list(self.data)[k*self.batch_size + i][8]`

Comment: thanks, I have solved the probelm.  by changing the x_input_ids = x_train[0] to x_input_ids = x_train[:,0] , the same as x_input_mask and x_segment_ids